# How to bind to a style attribute using [innerHtml] Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am able to style the html how I want using the ViewEncapsulation.  That is all good and fine.  But I want to be able to bind to a certain attribute, specifically the the background-color.  The class I use works just fine...

Here is the ViewEncapsulation part:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'legend-slot',
  templateUrl: `legend-slot.component.html`,
  styleUrls: ['legend-slot.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Here is the part I'm trying to return:

```
return `
  <div class="testCircle" [style.background-color]="getColor(layer.style)"></div>
  `;
```

This works fine using regular html.  I even just put something like red where the function is and it still doesn't work.  I tried using this in a pipe. But to no avail..

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export  class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {

  }
  transform(value: any, ...args): any {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

I could just use a bunch of NgIfs but I am not feeling like that is the best route to go down.

Comment: Make use of ngClass or programtically return backgoroud color names. But what you're trying to do is returning html element from ts component. This's React like pattern, angular doesn't follow this design. You should have that in view part. 
If you really don't want to use multiple ngIf use ngClass & have multiple conditions on same line.

Comment: Do you have a special reason to use `[innerHTML]`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I figured it would be a cleaner approach.  I decided to just make multiple ngIfs.  If an answer comes along I'll give it a try though.

Comment: @Shantanu I figured.  It seemed like it would clean things up.  I decided to just use multiple ngIfs.

Comment: Why looks like you are coming from React? Angular is a different thing, don't use innerHTML if you don't have to